# Semaphore and shared memory

Tags: c, linux, fork, shared-memory, semaphore

I try to write a program with 2 processes synchronized by a semaphore. The parent process generates a random number and saves it to shared memory. The child reads this number. It can only read if the parent has finished generating and parent can generate a new number only if the child reads it.

I do not know if my program runs correctly because I get a segmentation fault when I try to access `data->random_num = random;` or `data->random_num;`.

The code is:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const key_t sem_key = (key_t)0x12345678;
const key_t shm_key = (key_t)0x12339678;

struct shared_data{
  int random_num;
};

union semun{
  int val; //setval value
};

int sem_wait(int semafor_id){
  struct sembuf sb;
  sb.sem_num = 0;
  sb.sem_op = -1;
  sb.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

  return semop(semafor_id,&sb,1);
}

int sem_signal(int semafor_id){
  struct sembuf sb;
  sb.sem_num = 0;
  sb.sem_op = 1;
  sb.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;

  return semop(semafor_id,&sb,1);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

  int status;

  srand(time(NULL));
  //Create shared memory
  int memory_id = shmget(shm_key,sizeof(struct shared_data),0600|IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);
  if(memory_id < 0){
    printf("Shared memory creating failed\n");
    return 1;
  }

  //Create semafor
  int semafor_id = semget(sem_key,10, 0600|IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);
  if(semafor_id < 0){
    printf("SEMAFOR creating failed\n");
    return 1;
  }
  semctl(semafor_id,0,SETVAL,1); //init semafor

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid < 0){
    printf("FORK FAILED\n");
  }
  else if(pid > 0){

    printf("PARENT\n");
    int i;
    if(i = sem_wait(semafor_id) < 0){
      printf("Failed wait parent\n");
      return 1;
    }else{
      int random = rand() % 80;
      printf("Generate random number: %d\n",random);
      //Try attach memory for writting     
      void* address = shmat(memory_id, NULL ,0);
      if(address == NULL){
        printf("Failed to atach memory\n");
        return 1;
      }

      struct shared_data* data = (struct shared_data*) address;
      data->random_num = random;

      if(shmdt(address) != 0){
        printf("Failed to detach shared memory\n");
      }

      sleep(2); 
    }

    if(i = sem_signal(semafor_id) < 0){
      printf("Failed signal parent\n");
    }else{
      printf("Parent leave generating number\n");
    }

    //wait for child
    wait(&status);
    printf("Destroy semafor\n");
    semctl(semafor_id,0, IPC_RMID,0);
    printf("Destroy shared memory\n");
    shmctl(memory_id,IPC_RMID, 0);

    return 0; 
  }
  else{
    printf("CHILD\n");
    int j;
    //try to get semafor
    if(j = sem_wait(semafor_id) < 0){
      printf("FAILED wait child\n");
    }else{
      printf("Child reading data\n");
      void* address = shmat(memory_id, NULL ,0);
      if(address == NULL){
        printf("Failed to atach memory in child\n");
        return 1;
      }

      struct shared_data* data = (struct shared_data*) address;
      printf("Child read data %d\n",data->random_num);
      sleep(1);

      if(shmdt(address) != 0){
        printf("Failed to detach shared memory in child\n");
      }
    }   

    if(j = sem_signal(semafor_id) < 0){
      printf("Failed signal child\n");
    }else{
      printf("Leave data reading\n");
    }
    return 0;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the newer method is `mmap`.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to raise (about) a dozen warnings.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  A couple of the more trivial warnings: 1) parameter `argc` not used 2) parameter `argv[]` not used.  For these two warnings, declare main() as `int main( void )`   There are numerous more warnings to be fixed that are of a much more serious nature.

Comment: why declare a `union` type that only contains a single field?  Better yet, why declare a `union` type that is never used?

Comment: some statements, like: `if(j = sem_wait(semafor_id) < 0){` are missing a set of parens, so what is being compared is a bit obscure (and the compiler will complain)  Suggest: `if( (j = sem_wait(semafor_id) ) < 0){`

Comment: regarding these two statements: `const key_t sem_key = (key_t)0x12345678;
const key_t shm_key = (key_t)0x12339678;`   Why define the keys with the same value?

Comment: `sem_wait()` is a system function name (which you will need to access, not define your own function) and which can be accessed by `#include <semaphore.h>

Comment: from this page: <http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node69.html> "The first argument to shmget() is the key value (in our case returned by a call to ftok())."   So the code cannot just use some arbitrary value for the contents of the key

Comment: from the man page for `semget()` "The  semget() system call returns the System V semaphore set identifier
       associated with the argument key.  A new set  of  nsems  semaphores  is
       created  if  key  has the value IPC_PRIVATE or if no existing semaphore
       set is associated with key and IPC_CREAT is specified in semflg."   so the first field is not correct

Comment: regarding the call to `semctl()`.  Strongly suggest reading the man page as found at: <http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/semctl.htm> for the details, as the posted code is not correct.  And the code really needs to pay attention to the returned value

Comment: regarding this line: `sb.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node69.html`  What do you think it is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void* address = shmat(memory_id, NULL ,0);
```

I'm getting this error on that line (and another where shmat is called):

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

The man page says shmat returns a void pointer, so that's a clue that something is wrong. It turns out that adding this line (to get a missing prototype) fixes it:

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
```

EDIT: above replaces a prior answer that was a red herring.

P.S. It helps to remove the IPC_EXCL from your flags when testing, so
that if you get a crash you don't have to do the ipcs / ipcrm shuffle
constantly, to remove existing segments / semaphores before you can
create new ones.